# Why does 'plpgsql' not appear in the pg_extension table?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-extensions

I have two Postgres 9.1 installations.  One works properly, the other does not.

On the working installation:

```
dc=# select * from pg_extension;
extname  | extowner | extnamespace | extrelocatable | extversion | extconfig | extcondition 
----------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------
plpgsql  |       10 |           11 | f              | 1.0        |           | 
plperl   |       10 |           11 | f              | 1.0        |           | 
intarray |       10 |         2200 | t              | 1.0        |           | 
pgtap    |       10 |        66181 | t              | 0.94.0     |           | 
(4 rows)

dc=# select * from pg_language;
lanname  | lanowner | lanispl | lanpltrusted | lanplcallfoid | laninline | lanvalidator | lanacl 
----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------
internal |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2246 | 
c        |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2247 | 
sql      |       10 | f       | t            |             0 |         0 |         2248 | 
plpgsql  |       10 | t       | t            |         16392 |     16393 |        16394 | 
plperl   |       10 | t       | t            |         16397 |     16398 |        16399 | 
(5 rows)
```

On the 'broken' one:

```
dc=# select * from pg_extension;
extname  | extowner | extnamespace | extrelocatable | extversion | extconfig | extcondition 
----------+----------+--------------+----------------+------------+-----------+--------------
intarray |       10 |         2200 | t              | 1.0        |           | 
(1 row)

dc=# select * from pg_language;
lanname  | lanowner | lanispl | lanpltrusted | lanplcallfoid | laninline | lanvalidator | lanacl 
----------+----------+---------+--------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+--------
internal |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2246 | 
c        |       10 | f       | f            |             0 |         0 |         2247 | 
sql      |       10 | f       | t            |             0 |         0 |         2248 | 
plpgsql  |       10 | t       | t            |         27558 |     27559 |        27560 | 
plperl   |       10 | t       | t            |         27562 |     27563 |        27564 | 
(5 rows)
```

Is there any reason that `plpgsql` and `plperl` ought to be listed in `pg_language` but not in `pg_extension` on the 'broken' system, or is it truly broken? What is the 'cure'?

Comment: Weird. I wouldn't have expected plpgsql to appear as an extension at all, but when I look it is indeed shown as an extension. If someone had done a `DROP EXTENSION plpgsql` it would be missing from `pg_language` too. Somebody messing with the catalogs directly?

Comment: @CraigRinger: Not intentionally, anyway... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On PostgreSQL 9.1, it is possible to get to this state without directly manipulating the catalogs.

I started from having `plpgsql` as an extension, and did the following:

```
# DROP EXTENSION plpgsql CASCADE; -- do this only if you are prepared to lose your plpgsql functions, too
# \dx
                                     List of installed extensions
     Name      │ Version │ Schema │                            Description                             
───────────────┼─────────┼────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 btree_gin     │ 1.0     │ public │ support for indexing common datatypes in GIN
 btree_gist    │ 1.0     │ public │ support for indexing common datatypes in GiST
 dblink        │ 1.0     │ public │ connect to other PostgreSQL databases from within a database
 fuzzystrmatch │ 1.0     │ public │ determine similarities and distance between strings
 hstore        │ 1.0     │ public │ data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
 intarray      │ 1.0     │ public │ functions, operators, and index support for 1-D arrays of integers
 pgcrypto      │ 1.0     │ public │ cryptographic functions

# SELECT lanname FROM pg_language;
  lanname  
───────────
 internal
 c
 sql
 plpythonu

CREATE PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE plpgsql; -- this won't work in 9.3, for example
```

After this, I have no `plpgsql` as an extension, but it is listed among the languages.  You can define functions in this language as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the server would allow you to drop the "plpgsql" extension. It seems a case of somebody manually deleting the entry from pg_extension catalog table.

You can recreate the extension if it is available in the pg_available_extensions table. If that doesn't work, you can try inserting the required row for plpgsql.

Comment: you can actually drop plpgsql extension if for example other extensions (for example postgis_topology) don't depend on it:

> DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS plpgsql RESTRICT;
It removed extension and executing it second time showt info:

> NOTICE:  extension "plpgsql" does not exist, skipping
DROP EXTENSION